# Passing file opened from system call open() to function

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system, system-calls

I'm creating a function to copy an array of characters to a file in C. I get warnings about pointers, so I'm pretty sure that's the problem. In my main program, I make a system call:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *out_fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR, 0644); //Yes, I will fix the 3rd argument
    char arr[] = "hello";
    copyCharArr(arr, out_fd);
}
```

The copyCharArr() function is here:

```
int copyCharArr(char *arr[], int fd)
{
    int num_written = write(fd, arr, sizeof(arr));
    if(num_written == -1){
            printf("Unable to write file\n");
            return -1;
    }
    if(num_written != sizeof(arr)){
            printf("Unable to write entire file\n");
            return -1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

And here are the warnings:

```
options.c: In function ‘addFile’:
options.c:22: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
options.c:24: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘copyCharArr’ from incompatible pointer type
copies.h:5: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
```

Any help is appreciated as I am a bit rusty on pointers! I'm not even sure if it is possible to pass a file to a function like this.

Comment: `int *out_fd = open(...)` is incorrect, `open` returns an int, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several bugs and inaccuracies fixed in the code below. Please see the comments on details:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int copyCharArr(char *, const size_t, int); /* A prototype is mandatory as the 
                                         compiler had not seen copyCharArr() yet. */

/* int main(int argc, char *argv[]) */
int main(void) /* If argc and argv aren't used to not define them. */
{
  int out_fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR, 0644); /* open() returns int so declare 
                                                  out_fd as such. */
  char arr[] = "hello";
  copyCharArr(arr, sizeof arr, out_fd); /* As the size of arr gets lost when passing 
                                           it to a function pass it explicitly. 
                                           Pass sizeof arr - 1 if the "string"'s 
                                           0-terminator shall not be written to file.*/

  /* Do not forget to close the file. */
}


int copyCharArr(char * arr, const size_t s, int fd) /* Passing a char[] to a function 
                                                 let's it decay to a pointer to its 
                                                 1st element, that is char* here. 
                                                 That's also why we need to pass the 
                                                 size explcitly as s. */
{
  ssize_t result = write(fd, arr, s); /* write() returns ssize_t not int. */
  if (result == -1) {
      perror("write() failed"); /* Using this library function gives more details on 
                                   failure. Also the error goes to stderr, where error
                                   messages shall go. */
      return -1;
  }

  {
    size_t num_written = result;
    if (num_written != s) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to write entire file.\n"); /* Prints the error message to 
                                                             stderr, but to standard output. */
        return -1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(arr)` is 6, so you are writing a null byte to the file.  I'd get a compilation warning/error from comparing `num_written != s` (comparing signed and unsigned values: `comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]`).  There are times when using `int` is simpler — this is one of them.  Your types are pedantically correct, but lead to compiler warnings.  It is a tricky area; I go with 'no warnings' because leaving any warnings rapidly leads down a slippery slope.

Comment: Also, `open()` and `O_RDWR` are defined in `<fcntl.h>` rather than `<unistd.h>`.  Also, it would be better to use `int main(void)` since the arguments are not used — I get unused variable warnings (errors because of `-Werror` on the compilation command line).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the inaccuracy regarding what `write()` returns. Fixed this. Using `int` for each and everything is dangerous nat least in corner cases. Refering the number of bytes to write the question seems ambigious to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, I forgot to include `<fcntl.h>`, Fixed. Regarding the defintion of `argv` and `argc`: we do not know how the OP's code continues ... - I however agree to not define what not is used.

Comment: These are minor nits being picked.  As to length: yes, the question is ambiguous.  Strictly, since there won't be a newline at the end, it isn't a text file, so the null byte won't hurt in a binary file.  The major issue is that the OP probably wouldn't notice the null byte until there were several writes and then the data was re-read (which is the best justification for the `O_RDWR` as opposed to `O_WRONLY` mode for `open()`).  As to `int main(void)` vs … true, we don't know how the program continues, but I almost always make sure that what I post compiles cleanly as it stands.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Fair enough. Your last argument referring the usage of `argc` and `argv` is convincing. Source adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of errors:

```
int copyCharArr(char *arr[], int fd)
//                   ^^^^^^
//         Use  char arr[]
//         or
//              char* arr  
{
    // sizeof(arr) does not give you the length of the string.
    // it gives you the size of a pointer. You need strlen(arr)
    //                write(fd, arr, strlen(arr));  
    int num_written = write(fd, arr, sizeof(arr));
    if(num_written == -1){
            printf("Unable to write file\n");
            return -1;
    }

    // Once again, sizeof(arr) is not appropriate.
    // Use strlen(arr)
    if(num_written != sizeof(arr)){
            printf("Unable to write entire file\n");
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An updated version.

```
int copyCharArr(char *arr, int fd)
{
    int len = strlen(arr);
    int num_written = write(fd, arr, len);
    if(num_written == -1){
            printf("Unable to write file\n");
            return -1;
    }

    if(num_written != len){
            printf("Unable to write entire file\n");
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`. `write()` returns `ssize_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

open returns a low level integer file descriptor. It is not valid to use an int pointer)

```
int fd = open(...)   // correct
```

Not

```
int *fd = open(...)  // error
```